# Has SO's attitude towards "bug reports" changed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, bug-reporting-process

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43288884/1016716) on SO asked today about a bug someone just discovered in a browser, and the question attracted downvotes and comments like "Stack Overflow is not the *bug reporting site locator*." and "Closing this question as off-topic" and such.

However, it was a duplicate of earlier questions - apparently the bug has been around since at least 2013 - and those earlier ones were received quite positively, one even having 25 upvotes.

So why was this latest one dissed like that? By the time I closed it as a duplicate, it already had 4 close votes for being off topic. Obviously people didn't even think about checking for duplicates before I came in.

Has this site's policy changed since 2013 then? Are posts complaining about bugs in browsers no longer welcome?

Comment: Link? I find it hard to believe that a majority if viewers would consider _"StackOverflow is not the bug reporting site locator."_ to be correct.

Comment: Or was it posted on main instead of meta?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, on SO, not on MSO. Sorry if that was ambiguous.

Comment: There's another ambiguity in your question - was it a bug with Stack Overflow, or a bug with the browser?

Comment: The question closes with: *I've never reported a bug before. Is there a smart way/place to do this so somebody will actually see it?*. The commenters are **addressing that part**. No, Stack Overflow is not a issue tracker tracker.

Answer (score 3):

If the "bug report" was posted on SO instead of MSO, it *is* off-topic.

Bug reports about Stack Overflow should be posted here on meta, or perhaps even on [Stack Exchange's meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Bug reports about other software should be submitted to said software's helpdesk, not to MSO.

To answer your question:

This isn't a change in attitude. Bug reports have always been off-topic for SO.

Comment: No no, not a bug report about the site.

Comment: A bug report about _other_ software?.. This is why you link to the question, when asking a meta question about a question on main.

Comment: Let's hope my edit makes the question clearer. But I did say "a bug in a browser" from the start.

Comment: A single word that's easily overlooked ;-)

Comment: Of course, if you're posting about a bug in order to either share or find a workaround you can use while coding, that's perfectly welcome. (But I don't know that anyone would call that a "report".) That's why the original used for the duplicate closure in this case is okay.